# Сравнить два значения и показать ошибку

Tags: html, jquery

Нужно, чтобы после ввода значения в `max` сразу происходило сравнение.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  if ($('#minCost').val() > $('#maxCost').val() {
      alert('Значение ' + $('#minCost').val() + 'должно быть меньше, чем ' + $('#maxCost').val());
    }
  }));

//blur вместо change тоже не помогло
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="min">
<input id="max">
```

Comment: `$('input').on("change, keyup", function() { if (+$('#minCost').val() > +$('#maxCost').val() {`

Comment: @Igor спасибо, а вот такая ситуация: эту группу инпутов можно сделать неактивной по нажатию на `radio`, юзер увидел ошибку, нажал "ок", попереключал `radio`, - по факту проблема осталась, но ошибку он опять не увидит. нужно дополнительно проверять на наличие ошибки, когда инпут становится активным?

Comment: да. сделайте анонимный обработчик отдельной функцией и вызывайте ее, когда инпуты делаются активными на клик по радиокнопке